# Are static instances used asynchronously?

Tags: c#, design-patterns, web, singleton

I have read a lot of questions related to this, but I haven't found a solid answer, that's why I decided to post my own question about it.

I have seen a lot of web applications and web services that Implement the Singleton design pattern, but lately I've been thinking that there's not a real reason why this should be a good idea(let me know if I'm wrong)

My guess: No, I think it will use the same instance for all requests which will make my code slower and won't let me take advantage of the garbage collector.

Ex: Request 1 Calls MethodInStaticInstance() Let's say it takes 2 seconds. 
    Request 2 Calls MethodInStaticInstance() Waits till Request 1 is done to call the method because     it is been used. (I might be wrong, this is how I see it, I don't know if this is true or not)

I guess the only way having static instance might be helpful in a web app is if the static resources can be used asynchronously. What do you think?

Comment: Of course they can be used asynchronously with the possibility for race conditions and other issues. By separate threads, of course

Answer (score 0):

There is nothing special about `static` instances, their methods run on the same thread as their caller.

So no, static instances are not used "asynchronously" unless their callers are on separate threads.

In the context of a web app, there is the very real possibility of a race condition if two users invoke the same function at similar times if the method is not thread-safe.

Answer (score 0):

Statics are useful when you don't want to instantiate an object to run a method.  Consider this example:

```
public class MyMath
{
  public int sum(int a, int b)
  {
    return a + b;
  }
}
```

To get a sum you'd need to do the following:

```
  MyMath m = new MyMath();
  int c = m.sum(1, 2);
```

However, if `sum` were static you could do the following and avoid unnecessarily creating an object:

```
  int c = MyMath.sum(1,2);
```

Now, as to using it asynchronously: There is no reason you can't.  It's no more or less thread safe than a non-static class (although with non-static classes you can use separate *instances* in separate threads if you wanted).

EDIT: The Singleton

Singleton patterns are generally used when you want to ensure that only one instantiation of an object happens.  The reasons vary, for wanting to do this.  I've used it in the past to limit the number of connections to a resource.  Whether you can use this asynchronously or not depends on your implementation.  You could implement locks to prevent multiple calls on a method from running simultaneously, but you would have to specifically do that.